# sorting posts from query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have made a query on `posts` (which is included in a has_many belongs_to assoc. with users). So, with this query, I have a selection of `posts` in `@selected_posts` is there any way I can categorize and sort the users that have posts included in this query and sort them by name with a count of posts? ( Like **Mike (6)** as link to Mike's 6 posts) for example?

Comment: In a `@matches.each do |post|` I can pull pretty much anything I want, including the user object attached to each post. Just not sure as to how to utilize the @selected_posts to make some links that show the users for that specific set of posts

Comment: Is this real production code or just playing around? If this is production code you should really think about using a full text search tool with support for faceting (this kind of numbering on associated models).

Comment: definitely real production: i'll look into that, thanks for the suggestion. if you have any docs or resources for that, please provide :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_by. There is excellent documentation on this in the api docs here http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by